# The type has no constructors defined

Tags: c#

I am trying to inherit a container class that is part of a another DLL which has the following structure

```
namespace MySdk
{
    // Summary:
    //     Container class used to encapsulate individual mark details 
    public class MathsReport: IEnumerable
    {
        // Summary:
        //     A list of mark details.
        public List<Mark> Marks;

        // Summary:
        //     Get access to the C# IEnumerator interface of the mark reports list.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The IEnumerator interface to the list of mark reports.
        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

My Code

```
public class MyReport : MathsReport
{
}
```

It throws `The type MySdk.MathsReport has no constructors defined`.

Why it is throwing error and restricting me from inherting. And how can I overcome it?

Comment: The code you've presented would be fine, but presumably `MathsReport` *actually* declares a constructor, but with internal/private access. Your subclass would need to have access to that constructor to chain to it. Are you able to look at and/or change the code in the other DLL?

Comment: The code shown for `MathsReport` looks pretty similar to a decompiled version, you should check if it has a constructor and if it does (I'm pretty sure it does), what access modifier that constructor has.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, as mentioned by @ Lasse V. Karlsen, it is a decompiled code and the above code is what I see in the DLL. There is no other code in class MathsReport

Comment: Well the DLL just contains IL, so you must be doing something to get back C# - and note that that's not even valid C#. (You wouldn't be able to compile `MathsReport` as presented.) So I strongly suspect there *is* more in the DLL, but however you're viewing it only shows public members.

Comment: @JonSkeet is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: It's hard to answer that without more information - such as how the code is *actually* written, and whether or not you can modify it. If the class only has private constructors and you can't modify it, then no, you can't derive from it. (It's not clear what your question has to do with events, by the way... Why have you included those tags?)

Comment: @JonSkeet I cannot modify as it is a third party DLL :(

Comment: If you cannot modify it you cannot inherit from it.

Comment: Right, it would have been good to know that before. Basically, if there are no accessible constructors, you can't derive from it. Use composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: have a look here, it might be helpful: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9178/modify-code-with-ilspy

Answer (score 0):

To reiterate what has been said in the comments, the `MathsReport` has no public constructors which means you cannot, effectively, inherit it.

However you can add extension methods to do various "extra" things without actually inheriting the class. Obviously this isn't the same as actual inheritance, but it might be enough for your use case.

Example of an extension class:

```
public static class MathsReportExtensions
{
  public static Mark GetBestMark(this MathsReport mathsReport)
  {
    //this is just a sample code which returns the first Mark from the collection
    return mathsReport.First();
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
using NamespaceToExtensionClass;

//...

public void SomeMethodUsingMathsReport(MathsReport mathsReport)
{
  var bestMark = mathsReport.GetBestMark();
}
```